# Create new database with idb-files from another database

Tags: mysql, macos-monterey

I recently upgraded to Mac OS Monterey, which gave me a bit of a headache. Due to my own stupidity I lost my whole development MYSQL-database, although I did manage to backup all of my idb-files. But even the frm-files got lost.

I searched stackoverflow for a solution to recover my database structure, but they all required those frm-files, which I don't have.

Now I have a bit of a problem. Is it somehow possible to recover the database-structure from only those idb-files? Ie: tables including columns. Ideally I would like to have the create-statements for those tables and columns, so I can recreate the database.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: when you do not have the `.frm` files you are lost, and if you have them chances are BIG that you still cannot recover, see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16911/162995

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions posted for reattaching existing .ibd files to tables once you create them. For example https://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/

It's a lot of meticulous work.

But it's up to you to reconstruct the tables with CREATE TABLE statements. You would need to reconstruct them exactly as they were before, to be compatible with the .ibd files.

I don't know any way to produce the original CREATE TABLE statement given only its .ibd file.

Sorry, it's likely that your database is not recoverable.

Comment: This looks promising (but no guarantees...): https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?156,695461,695461#msg-695461

Comment: @Luuk, Indeed, but Aleksandr K. is the only person I'd trust to use that solution! :-)